# copy_tree: The network path was not found

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to set up a simple script to copy updates from one office server to a few others. However, I'm running into a network path not found error. The path does exist, but the script is not finding it.

```
# DC @@Toolbox location
dc_toolbox = r"\\dc\DATA\@@Toolbox"

# List of @@Toolbox directories to copy to
office_toolboxes = [r"\\atl\data\@@Toolbox",
                    r"\\kc\Data\CLIENTS\@@Toolbox",
                    r"\\ny\DATA\Valuation\@@Toolbox",
                    r"\\cle\data\VALUATION\@@Toolbox",
                    r"\\cmh\DATA\CLIENTS\@@Toolbox",
                    r"\\presidio\data\Valuation\GoVal\@@Toolbox"]

# Copying to all other offices
for tool in office_toolboxes:
    copy_tree(dc_toolbox, tool)
```

When the loop reaches the kc server I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 139, in copy_tree
mkpath(dst, verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 76, in mkpath
"could not create '%s': %s" % (head, exc.args[-1]))
distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: could not create '\\kc-s4\Data\': The network path was not found
```

Anyone have any clues why this error is popping up?